# Classification: Selecting final label using prior information on class distribution

Tags: r, classification, modeling, prior

Using R, let's say that I have the following (dummy) data.

```
data(iris)
iris2 <- as.data.frame(scale(iris[,1:4]))
head(iris2)

> head(iris2)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1   -0.8976739  1.01560199    -1.335752   -1.311052
2   -1.1392005 -0.13153881    -1.335752   -1.311052
3   -1.3807271  0.32731751    -1.392399   -1.311052
4   -1.5014904  0.09788935    -1.279104   -1.311052
5   -1.0184372  1.24503015    -1.335752   -1.311052
6   -0.5353840  1.93331463    -1.165809   -1.048667
```

These columns represent the end result of 4 scoring models, one model for each label, and I now need to select the final label for each case. One straightforward way would be to use the maximum score for each row, for example, like this:

```
iris3 <- cbind(
  iris2,
  lable_num=max.col(iris2,ties.method="first")
)
head(iris3)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width lable_num
1   -0.8976739  1.01560199    -1.335752   -1.311052         2
2   -1.1392005 -0.13153881    -1.335752   -1.311052         2
3   -1.3807271  0.32731751    -1.392399   -1.311052         2
4   -1.5014904  0.09788935    -1.279104   -1.311052         2
5   -1.0184372  1.24503015    -1.335752   -1.311052         2
6   -0.5353840  1.93331463    -1.165809   -1.048667         2
```

This yields a label distribution of

```
> table(iris3$lable_num)/length(iris3$lable_num)

        1         2         3         4 
0.1866667 0.3400000 0.2266667 0.2466667
```

**However**, since I have reliable prior information on this distribution, what is a good way to select the final labels? For example, I know that the distributions should be `20% 20% 40% 20%`. I cannot change how the scores have been calculated.

I could do a rank for each of the 4 scoring models, and fill each of the labels by selecting by descending rank, but are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have scores for four different categories that are given to you and you need to use them to guess the class assignment. On another hand, you know *a priori* proportions of cases that should fall to different classes and you want to combine those two sources of information.

My suggestion would be to find such vector of weights $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_k)$ that would be used to weight the scores in each of the columns, so to make proportions of final classifications closer to expected proportions (so the only thing that changes in your procedure is that you re-weight the scores). For this you need some kind of optimization algorithm and function to minimize. Since you are dealing with contingency tables, the fist loss function that comes to mind is [$\chi^2$ statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test)

$$ \chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(\hat n_i - N \pi_i)^2}{N \pi_i} $$

where $N$ is your sample size, $\hat n_i$ is total number of cases classified into $i$-th class and $\pi_i$ is target proportion of cases to be classified into $i$-th class.

```r
data <- as.matrix(iris2)
N <- nrow(data)

# weight the columns and classify
weightCols <- function(beta) {
  max.col(t(t(data) * beta))
}

# compute proportions of classes
weightedProp <- function(beta) {
  prop.table(table(weightCols(beta)))
}

# chi-squared loss function
chiSqLoss <- function(beta) {
  guess <- as.numeric(table(weightCols(beta)))
  Npi <- N*target
  sum((guess - Npi)^2/Npi)
}

# target proportions
target <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2)

# use some optimization algorithm to minimize chi^2
fit <- optim(c(1,1,1,1), chiSqLoss)
```

that returns

```r
weightedProp(c(1,1,1,1)) # no weighting
## 
##         1         2         3         4 
## 0.1866667 0.3400000 0.2266667 0.2466667 

weightedProp(fit$par) # optimal weights
## 
##         1         2         3         4 
## 0.1600000 0.3333333 0.3266667 0.1800000
```

As you can see, the fit isn't perfect given your `target`, but it is slightly better then when applying no weights. You can also try different optimization algorithms and/or loss functions to minimize, that could possibly work better for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just what I was looking for. One question though, why is it that the result is not better than that? Sure, it is closer, but what does it tell about the problem and the method used?

Comment: @Figaro because it still depends on your data (the scores) - the scores within columns stay relatively untouched while between columns are changed. I guess that you still want to trust the scores but only adjust them and this is what it does. However remember that this procedure does not have to improve the initial scores were good I guess it may make things worse - if I were you I'd cross-validate the results to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing one result from different model is not the correct way. On training data set where you know the output you might get better accuracy than choosing single best model or combined models (through ensembling or blending) but on new data set the model will mostly have very bad predictions.

Please go though the below link for detailed explanation about model ensemble & blending.

http://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/

In a nutshell, if you have 2 different models one with 70% accuracy & other with 80% accuracy (with better prediction for particular class) you can combine the results through say weighted mean based on accuracy. This way if one model is able to predict particular cases better than others you will be able to use it in overall model.

There are multiple packages available in R as well, Please refer to below link for 'caret' -

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caretEnsemble/vignettes/caretEnsemble-intro.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you are missing the core problem of my question. As I said, I cannot change how the scores have been calculated, so I'm stuck with one score for each class. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: First, I'm not proposing to change scores. From classification model you can get output as each class with probability, so for 3 class problem you can get 3 probabilities (at the end the one with highest is assigned as prediction which you are showing in the question). All I'm saying is you take the output of all classes & use weighted average of all 4 models.

Comment: There are 4 models, but each model only outputs 1 score, the score for that particular class (they are one-class models). Imho, there is nothing to create an ensemble from, because there is no training data for the true classification (only the distribution).

Comment: If the models are predicting 4 different labels then at best you can multiply the probability by each model accuracy (or precision based on the objective) & then choose highest as final label.

Comment: Ah, true. But in this case, this is, too, information that is not available.

Comment: Well then at most what you can do is get the similarity score between the distributions (known & predicted) using KS test, cosine similarity or other alternatives. But I do think it's too much approximation. Hope someone else has better solution than this.